# How to make a certain set of values available in just one row

Tags: mysql

I would like to set up a database for a example project I have. I have chosen a driving school and work with tables including teachers, pupils, cars, time_lessons and bookings. The code can be seen in the code section. The four first tables i.e. teachers, pupils, cars and time_lessons are all foreign keys in bookings.

My issue is that I need certian combinations of these foreign keys to be available once. Let me clarify:
- A teacher cannot teach a same time_lessons twice
- A pupil cannot drive in a driving time_lessons twice
- A car cannot be used during the same time_lessons twice
- However a time in time_lessons can be used multiple times providing you have a pupil, a teacher and a car that haven't already been booked in that time.

How do I set this up?

See code below to see what I've done so far...

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS c4trafik;
CREATE DATABASE c4trafik;
USE c4trafik; 

CREATE TABLE teachers(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t_fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    t_lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    auth_lvl INT DEFAULT 3
);

CREATE TABLE pupils(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    p_fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    p_lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    persnr CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    telnr VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    to_pay INT DEFAULT 0,
    has_pay INT DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE cars(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    regnr VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    auto_gear BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);

CREATE TABLE time_lessons(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    t_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    les_type VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Driving Lesson'
);

CREATE TABLE bookings(
    teachers_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pupils_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cars_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time_lessons_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(teachers_id) REFERENCES teachers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(pupils_id) REFERENCES pupils(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(cars_id) REFERENCES cars(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(time_lessons_id) REFERENCES time_lessons(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(teachers_id, pupils_id, cars_id, time_lessons_id) 
);

INSERT INTO teachers (t_fname, t_lname, auth_lvl) VALUES
('Ali', 'Alisson', 1),
('Adam', 'Adamsson', 2),
('Noah', 'Noahsson', 3);

INSERT INTO pupils(p_fname, p_lname, persnr, email, telnr, to_pay, has_pay) VALUES
('Jakob', 'Jaboksson', '8702111254', 'pupil1@gmail.com','0704585962', 2800, 2800),
('Hassan','Hassansson', '9504234858' ,NULL,'0704125463',5000,1000),
('Mona','Monasson', '9410118547',NULL, NULL, 10200, NULL);

INSERT INTO cars (regnr, auto_gear) VALUES
('MNS111', false),
('OJS111', true),
('MNF111', false);

INSERT INTO time_lessons (t_start, t_end ) VALUES
('2019-06-10 08:00:00', '2019-06-10 08:40:00'),
('2019-06-10 08:50:00', '2019-06-10 09:30:00'),
('2019-06-10 09:40:00', '2019-06-10 10:20:00'),
('2019-06-10 10:30:00', '2019-06-10 11:10:00'),
('2019-06-10 11:20:00', '2019-06-10 12:00:00'),
('2019-06-10 13:10:00', '2019-06-10 13:50:00'),
('2019-06-10 14:00:00', '2019-06-10 14:40:00'),
('2019-06-10 14:50:00', '2019-06-10 15:30:00'),
('2019-06-10 15:40:00', '2019-06-10 16:20:00');

INSERT INTO bookings(teachers_id ,pupils_id, cars_id, time_lessons_id) VALUES
(1,2,1,1),(2,1,1,1),
(1,2,1,2),(2,1,2,2),
(1,1,1,3),(2,2,1,3);
-- Ska ge error om man duplicerar!!
-- Find main admin
SELECT t_fname, t_lname FROM teachers WHERE auth_lvl = 1;

-- How many manual geared cars?
SELECT COUNT(*) AS manually_geared FROM cars
WHERE auto_gear = false;

-- all booked student
SELECT p_fname, p_lname FROM bookings
INNER JOIN pupils ON pupils.id = bookings.pupils_id
GROUP BY p_lname, p_fname;

-- What time will each student drive?
SELECT p_fname, p_lname, t_start, t_end FROM bookings
INNER JOIN pupils ON pupils.id = bookings.pupils_id
INNER JOIN time_lessons ON time_lessons.id = bookings.time_lessons_id
ORDER BY p_lname, p_fname, t_start;

-- All time_lessons for teacher number 1
SELECT t_fname, p_fname, p_lname, t_start, t_end FROM bookings
INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = bookings.teachers_id
INNER JOIN pupils ON pupils.id = bookings.pupils_id
INNER JOIN time_lessons ON time_lessons.id = bookings.time_lessons_id
WHERE teachers.id = 1;
```

So what I'm wondering is do I change my structure? Am I missing some code to make what I mentioned above work.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as we are missing  expected results.

Comment: I think your MySQL setup is complete. I'm sure you're not only going to use MySQL for this project? There must be something to interact with the database, PHP for instance. You can check with PHP which cars and teachers are free for a certain time slot, and only present those as possible selections. To prevent race conditions you could check again before inserting new data in the database, using a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A teacher cannot teach a same time_lessons twice*

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `(teacher_id,time_lesson_id)` tuple in the `booking`, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX booking_UX1 ON booking (teacher_id,time_lesson_id)
```

This will disallow rows with duplicates of a combination of values. If an attempt to `INSERT` a new row (or `UPDATE` and existing row) would cause two rows to have the same values, the statement will fail with error 1062 "Duplicate entry '' for key ".

---

*A pupil cannot drive in a driving time_lessons twice*

A UNIQUE index will prevent duplicates:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX booking_UX2 ON booking (pupil_id,time_lesson_id)
```

---

(My preference is for entity tables be named in the *singular*, to name what *one* row represents.)